# How to add voice-over to 3rd-party youtube videos? (play video and audio from diff. sources)

Tags: web-apps, audio, youtube

I would like to embed a youtube video owned by a third party with my own voice-over.  Due to copyright reasons, I do not wish to download or recreate the actual youtube video.

Is there a webplayer (script to be inserted in my website) that allows to simultaneously play youtube videos and add custom audio and keep them in sync?

**Note**: I agree that it would be better for me to ask for permission to use the copyrighted video and explain what I have in mind. But unfortunately this is not an option. I had cases where a product manager of content company X wanted me to use their content as I wished, but their legal department did not want to make an exception from hosting the content themselves.

Comment: Have you checked out the youtube iframe api? It should be possible to write some js code that can do it.